# org.jboss.resource.security.SecureIdentityLoginModule problems decrypting password on jboss startup

Tags: java, encryption, jboss, datasource, blowfish

I am running on jboss 5.1. I have a datasource that is configured with a security domain and an encrypted password.
here are my xml files:

login-config.xml

```
<!-- Example usage of the SecureIdentityLoginModule -->
<application-policy name="myDS-db-domain">
    <authentication>
        <login-module code="com.mobimate.jboss.resource.security.SecureIdentityLoginModule" flag="required">
            <module-option name="username">username</module-option>
            <module-option name="password">encryptedpassword1</module-option>
            <module-option name="managedConnectionFactoryName">jboss.jca:name=jdbc/myDS,service=LocalTxCM</module-option>
        </login-module>
    </authentication>
</application-policy>
```

myDS-ds.xml

```
<datasources>
    <local-tx-datasource>
        <jndi-name>jdbc/myDS</jndi-name>
        <connection-url>jdbc:mysql://db.local/myDS?enableQueryTimeouts=false</connection-url>
        <driver-class>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</driver-class>
        <security-domain>myDS-db-domain</security-domain>
        <min-pool-size>5</min-pool-size>
        <max-pool-size>60</max-pool-size>
        <blocking-timeout-millis>30000</blocking-timeout-millis>
        <idle-timeout-minutes>1</idle-timeout-minutes>
        <set-tx-query-timeout/>
        <background-validation>true</background-validation>
        <background-validation-minutes>3</background-validation-minutes>
        <exception-sorter-class-name>com.mysql.jdbc.integration.jboss.ExtendedMysqlExceptionSorter</exception-sorter-class-name>
        <valid-connection-checker-class-name>com.mysql.jdbc.integration.jboss.MysqlValidConnectionChecker</valid-connection-checker-class-name>
        <connection-property name="characterEncoding">UTF-8</connection-property>
        <metadata>
            <type-mapping>mySQL</type-mapping>
        </metadata>
    </local-tx-datasource>
</datasources>
```

ejb2-timer-service.xml

```
<server>
<!-- ==================================================================== -->
<!-- J2EE Timer Service                                                   -->
<!-- ==================================================================== -->
<!--
    A persistence policy that persists timers to a database.

    The 2 supported db persistence plugins are:
      org.jboss.ejb.txtimer.GeneralPurposeDatabasePersistencePlugin
      org.jboss.ejb.txtimer.OracleDatabasePersistencePlugin

    The table name defaults to "TIMERS". It can be overriden using the
     'TimersTable' attribute if the persistence plugin supports it.
     When overriding the timers table, an optional schema can be specified
     using the syntax [schema.]table
-->
    <mbean code="org.jboss.ejb.txtimer.DatabasePersistencePolicy" name="jboss.ejb:service=EJBTimerService,persistencePolicy=database">
        <!-- DataSourceBinding ObjectName -->
        <depends optional-attribute-name="DataSource">jboss.jca:service=DataSourceBinding,name=jdbc/myDS</depends>
        <!-- The plugin that handles database persistence -->
        <attribute name="DatabasePersistencePlugin">org.jboss.ejb.txtimer.GeneralPurposeDatabasePersistencePlugin</attribute>
        <!-- The timers table name -->
        <attribute name="TimersTable">TIMERS</attribute>
        <depends>jboss.jdbc:datasource=jdbc/myDS,service=metadata</depends>
    </mbean>

    <!-- A persistence policy that does not persist the timer
    <mbean code="org.jboss.ejb.txtimer.NoopPersistencePolicy" name="jboss.ejb:service=EJBTimerService,persistencePolicy=noop"/>
    -->

    <!-- A retry policy that uses a fixed interval in milli seconds -->
    <mbean code="org.jboss.ejb.txtimer.FixedDelayRetryPolicy" name="jboss.ejb:service=EJBTimerService,retryPolicy=fixedDelay">
        <attribute name="Delay">100</attribute>
    </mbean>
    <!-- An EJB Timer Service that is Tx aware -->
    <mbean code="org.jboss.ejb.txtimer.EJBTimerServiceImpl" name="jboss.ejb:service=EJBTimerService">
        <attribute name="TimerIdGeneratorClassName">org.jboss.ejb.txtimer.UUIDTimerIdGenerator</attribute>
        <attribute name="TimedObjectInvokerClassName">org.jboss.ejb.txtimer.TimedObjectInvokerImpl</attribute>
        <depends optional-attribute-name="RetryPolicy">jboss.ejb:service=EJBTimerService,retryPolicy=fixedDelay</depends>
        <depends optional-attribute-name="PersistencePolicy">jboss.ejb:service=EJBTimerService,persistencePolicy=database</depends>
        <depends optional-attribute-name="TransactionManagerFactory" proxy-type="org.jboss.tm.TransactionManagerFactory">
            jboss:service=TransactionManager
        </depends>
    </mbean>
</server>
```

***encryptedpassword1*** was generated a while ago using the command :

```
java -cp client/jboss-logging-spi.jar:lib/jbosssx.jar org.jboss.resource.security.SecureIdentityLoginModule password
```

from the jboss root directory.

This encrypted password works and the jboss starts and connects to the DB.
When I run the same command I get ***newencryptedpassword2***.
If I put this into the login-config.xml file, jboss will not start, it will fail on trying to create the timer table and get an authentication error.

Here is the stack trace from the server og file:

```
2014-02-09 17:00:32,096 (main) INFO  [org.jboss.resource.connectionmanager.ConnectionFactoryBindingService] Bound ConnectionManager 'jboss.jca:service=DataSourceBinding,name=jdbc/myDS' to JNDI name 'java:jdbc/wmlive'
2014-02-09 17:00:32,119 (main) ERROR [org.jboss.ejb.txtimer.GeneralPurposeDatabasePersistencePlugin] Cannot create timer table
java.lang.SecurityException: Unauthenticated caller:null
    at org.jboss.security.integration.JBossSecuritySubjectFactory.createSubject(JBossSecuritySubjectFactory.java:92)
    at org.jboss.resource.connectionmanager.BaseConnectionManager2.getSubject(BaseConnectionManager2.java:687)
    at org.jboss.resource.connectionmanager.BaseConnectionManager2.allocateConnection(BaseConnectionManager2.java:495)
    at org.jboss.resource.connectionmanager.BaseConnectionManager2$ConnectionManagerProxy.allocateConnection(BaseConnectionManager2.java:941)
    at org.jboss.resource.adapter.jdbc.WrapperDataSource.getConnection(WrapperDataSource.java:89)
    at org.jboss.ejb.plugins.cmp.jdbc.SQLUtil.tableExists(SQLUtil.java:1037)
    at org.jboss.ejb.txtimer.GeneralPurposeDatabasePersistencePlugin.createTableIfNotExists(GeneralPurposeDatabasePersistencePlugin.java:142)
    at org.jboss.ejb.txtimer.DatabasePersistencePolicy.startService(DatabasePersistencePolicy.java:104)
    at org.jboss.system.ServiceMBeanSupport.jbossInternalStart(ServiceMBeanSupport.java:376)
    at org.jboss.system.ServiceMBeanSupport.jbossInternalLifecycle(ServiceMBeanSupport.java:322)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor118.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ReflectedDispatcher.invoke(ReflectedDispatcher.java:157)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.dispatch(Invocation.java:96)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:88)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.AbstractMBeanInvoker.invoke(AbstractMBeanInvoker.java:264)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:668)
    at org.jboss.system.server.jmx.LazyMBeanServer.invoke(LazyMBeanServer.java:283)
    at org.jboss.system.microcontainer.ServiceProxy.invoke(ServiceProxy.java:189)
    at $Proxy43.start(Unknown Source)
    at org.jboss.system.microcontainer.StartStopLifecycleAction.installAction(StartStopLifecycleAction.java:42)
    at org.jboss.system.microcontainer.StartStopLifecycleAction.installAction(StartStopLifecycleAction.java:37)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.action.SimpleControllerContextAction.simpleInstallAction(SimpleControllerContextAction.java:62)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.action.AccessControllerContextAction.install(AccessControllerContextAction.java:71)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractControllerContextActions.install(AbstractControllerContextActions.java:51)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractControllerContext.install(AbstractControllerContext.java:348)
    at org.jboss.system.microcontainer.ServiceControllerContext.install(ServiceControllerContext.java:297)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.install(AbstractController.java:1652)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.incrementState(AbstractController.java:938)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:1082)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:988)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:826)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:556)
    at org.jboss.system.ServiceController.doChange(ServiceController.java:688)
    at org.jboss.system.ServiceController.start(ServiceController.java:460)
    at org.jboss.system.deployers.ServiceDeployer.start(ServiceDeployer.java:163)
    at org.jboss.system.deployers.ServiceDeployer.deploy(ServiceDeployer.java:99)
    at org.jboss.system.deployers.ServiceDeployer.deploy(ServiceDeployer.java:46)
    at org.jboss.deployers.spi.deployer.helpers.AbstractSimpleRealDeployer.internalDeploy(AbstractSimpleRealDeployer.java:62)
    at org.jboss.deployers.spi.deployer.helpers.AbstractRealDeployer.deploy(AbstractRealDeployer.java:55)
    at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployerWrapper.deploy(DeployerWrapper.java:179)
    at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.doDeploy(DeployersImpl.java:1454)
    at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.doInstallParentFirst(DeployersImpl.java:1172)
    at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.doInstallParentFirst(DeployersImpl.java:1193)
    at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.install(DeployersImpl.java:1113)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractControllerContext.install(AbstractControllerContext.java:348)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.install(AbstractController.java:1652)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.incrementState(AbstractController.java:938)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:1082)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:988)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:826)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:556)
    at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.process(DeployersImpl.java:789)
    at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.main.MainDeployerImpl.process(MainDeployerImpl.java:699)
    at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.repository.MainDeployerAdapter.process(MainDeployerAdapter.java:117)
    at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.repository.ProfileDeployAction.install(ProfileDeployAction.java:70)
    at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.repository.AbstractProfileAction.install(AbstractProfileAction.java:53)
    at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.repository.AbstractProfileService.install(AbstractProfileService.java:403)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractControllerContext.install(AbstractControllerContext.java:348)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.install(AbstractController.java:1652)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.incrementState(AbstractController.java:938)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:1082)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:988)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.install(AbstractController.java:778)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.install(AbstractController.java:543)
    at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.repository.AbstractProfileService.registerProfile(AbstractProfileService.java:308)
    at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.ProfileServiceBootstrap.start(ProfileServiceBootstrap.java:256)
    at org.jboss.bootstrap.AbstractServerImpl.start(AbstractServerImpl.java:461)
    at org.jboss.Main.boot(Main.java:221)
    at org.jboss.Main$1.run(Main.java:556)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

I am using the exact jboss server I used to generate the original encrypted password, when connecting directly with the user/pass to the db in plain text or with a mysql client all is ok, using the original encrypted password works, my problem is that I want to change the db password but can not since the encrypted password will not work.

Answer (score 0):

Ok,
Just found out the reason,
it seems that when we did the configuration change in the first place, we added our own login-module code but no one remembered it, when generating an encryption, I must add to the classpath our own login-module classes.
classic information not passed through the ages :(